# Identify physical drive from drive letter

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I am trying to identify the hardware that my PowerShell based benchmark is running from. I can get the Drive letter easy enough, and with **Win32_Volume** I can get some useful information like disk format. And with **Win32_diskdrive** I can get some information about a drive itself. But how do I get from Win32_Volume to Win32_diskdrive? The latter has a DeviceID, but I can't see that ID referenced anywhere in the Win32_Volume data. I have also looked at **Win32_PhysicalMedia** and I don't see any breadcrumbs to follow there either. So, given PowerShell 2.0 & WMI, how does one get from a drive letter to the physical disk the volume that drive letter represents is housed on?

Comment: I think Get-Disk is PS 3.0, and I am limited to 2.0 for a number of reasons beyond my control. But I would have thought just with WMI it could be done.

Comment: Doh! I had found Get-Disk and knew it didn't work, and didn't follow the link. Sorry! Looks